# Error Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Ser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, registry

I got this problem while trying to disable or enable ports. It works well when Im using my friend's laptop but when I tried using my laptop, it give this error. Why was this happen and how to solve it? Thanks ^^

```
Private Sub DisableBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DisableBtn.Click
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord) 'this line gives error
        MessageBox.Show("Port are disable", "USB Disable", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Me.Hide()
        Login.Show()
    End Sub
    Private Sub EnableBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles EnableBtn.Click
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord) 'this line gives error
        MessageBox.Show("Port are enable", "USB Enable", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Me.Hide()
        Login.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: By default, the keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` are writable only by administrators. It's likely your friend is logged in as an administrator, while you are not. Alternatively, your friend might have changed the permissions on those keys.

Comment: oh so I need to have administrator right to solve this problem?

Comment: You can run as administrator, or give yourself access to those keys, yes. You can use`regedit` to give yourself write access to just those keys - just right-click on the key and click `Permissions...`. Don't give yourself more access than you actually require though, as that opens you up to security vulnerabilities (see Principle-of-least-privilege)

Comment: okay thank you for the reply ^^